# Find value of sibling children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find the value of span. When I click on anchor it should give me value inside span. It should be dynamic.Here is the html

```
<div class="member-info">
     <h2>Total Votes : <span>1</span></h2>
     <a href="3" class="btn-system btn-medium border-btn vote_btn" data-target="#danger" data-toggle="modal">Vote</a>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery code

```
 $('.vote_btn').on('click',function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        var method_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Home/vote/"+ id;

        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url : method_url,
            success:function(data)
            {

                if(data=='1')
                {
                     var votes = $(this).siblings('h2').children('span').text() ; alert(votes);
                    $("#vote_response").html('Thanks you and come back tomorrow to vote again.');
                }else if(data=='0')
                {
                    var votes = $(this).siblings('h2').children('span').text() ; alert(votes);
                    $("#vote_response").html('Sorry you have already voted today, please come back tomorrow to vote again.');
                }

                $('#response_modal').modal('show')
            }       
        }); 
    });
```

This code is giving me undefined value whereas I want to get the value available in span element when I click on anchor vote. Please help

Comment: when your ajax call is triggered.. in document ready or some click event?

Comment: its in click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot access $(this) in success function directly ,assign a variable and access it in success function

```
 $('.vote_btn').on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    var method_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Home/vote/"+ id;
    var $current_element = $(this);

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url : method_url,
        success:function(data)
        {

            if(data=='1')
            {
                 var votes = $current_element.siblings('h2').children('span').text() ; alert(votes);
                $("#vote_response").html('Thanks you and come back tomorrow to vote again.');
            }else if(data=='0')
            {
                var votes = $current_element.siblings('h2').children('span').text() ; alert(votes);
                $("#vote_response").html('Sorry you have already voted today, please come back tomorrow to vote again.');
            }

            $('#response_modal').modal('show')
        }       
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text()` instead of `.val()`. The `.val()` function is used for finding the value of inputs and the span element is not an input. The `.text()` function will find the text inside of the span.

```js
$('.vote_btn').on('click',function(){
  var votes = $(this).siblings('h2').children('span').text() ; alert(votes);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="member-info">
     <h2>Total Votes : <span>1</span></h2>
     <a href="3" class="btn-system btn-medium border-btn vote_btn" data-target="#danger" data-toggle="modal">Vote</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working. Its  giving empty alert.

Comment: Is there something else that may be causing the program, because with the available code you posted my answer works. Look at the example in my answer.

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery in your program?

Comment: Please see the code now. It is working outside ajax but not inside.

Comment: yes I have jquery... now I have posted the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Use .text() or .html() in place of .val() because span do not have value attribute

Comment: Not working. Its either giving undefined or empty.